# Cannot post user score in Facebook SDK for Unity

Tags: c#, android, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm working in a Unity3D game for android that uses the Facebook Unity SDK to store, retrieve the scores and make leaderboards, but I've found problems and I cannot figure out the reason.

I'm using:

- Unity Pro 5.3.3f1.
- Facebook Unity SDK 7.4.0.
- Graph API 2.5.

I posted the code which I think is making trouble. It sometimes works, but it mainly fails by not having required permissions or by stating a "not found" error.

The game is correctly configured in the Facebook developers web page.

--

```
public void RequestSetScore(FacebookScore facebookScore)
{
    if (FacebookManager.Instance.accessToken == null)
    {
        FacebookManager.Instance.OnRequestSetScoreError("Application has not logged in to Facebook yet.");
        return;
    }

    if (this.PermissionIsGranted("publish_actions"))
    {
        string requestUri;
        requestUri = string.Format("{0}/scores?score={1}",
            FacebookManager.Instance.accessToken.UserId,
            facebookScore.ScoreValue.ToString());

        FB.API(requestUri, HttpMethod.POST,
            scoreSetRequestresult =>
            {
                // Esto se ejecuta cuando la respuesta se ha recibido, no inmediatamente
                if (scoreSetRequestresult.Error != null)
                {
                    // This is an event of my class
                    FacebookManager.Instance.OnRequestSetScoreError(scoreSetRequestresult.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    // This is an event of my class
                    FacebookManager.Instance.OnRequestSetScoreSuccess();
                }
            }
        );
    }
    else
    {
        // Pedir permisos para publicar puntuaciones
        FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(FacebookManager.Instance.publishPermissions,
            permissionRequestresult =>
            {
                // Esto se ejecuta cuando la respuesta se ha recibido, no inmediatamente
                if (permissionRequestresult.Error != null)
                {
                    string requestUri;
                    requestUri = string.Format("{0}/scores?score={1}",
                        FacebookManager.Instance.accessToken.UserId,
                        facebookScore.ScoreValue.ToString());

                    FB.API(requestUri, HttpMethod.POST,
                        scoreSetRequestresult =>
                        {
                            // Esto se ejecuta cuando la respuesta se ha recibido, no inmediatamente
                            if (scoreSetRequestresult.Error != null)
                            {
                                // This is an event of my class
                                FacebookManager.Instance.OnRequestSetScoreError(scoreSetRequestresult.Error);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // This is an event of my class
                                FacebookManager.Instance.OnRequestSetScoreSuccess();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
                else
                {
                    // This is an event of my class
                    FacebookManager.Instance.OnRequestSetScoreError(permissionRequestresult.Error);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}

// Métodos auxiliares
private bool PermissionIsGranted(string permission)
{
    AccessToken token = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
    foreach (string grantedPermission in token.Permissions)
    {
        if (grantedPermission == permission)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

--

Comments about the code: The FacebookScore type is a struct that encapsulates a long, and allows me manipulate it bitwise to store more than one number. These methods belong to a singleton-like class that that is accesible at every point of the game, and is preserved through scene changes.

Any idea would be very valuable to me, thanks in advance.

Comment: purely a note, many people use the prime31 plugins, to get things done with FB.

Comment: The problem is solved. I was sending a 64 bit integer, but the Facebook Graph API can only accept a 32 bit unsigned integer.

Comment: you should pur that in as an answer, it will help people.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I was sending a 64 bit integer, but the Facebook Graph API can only accept a 32 bit unsigned integer.